# I can not install tm package

Tags: r, tm

I have big problem to install tm package in R

```
install.packages("tm")

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tm’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
```

Comment: Might be an internet issue.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45108484/3358272 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/45115975/3358272.

Comment: Maybe you'll be able to install it from github? See http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/github.html: How to install a package from GitHub